# Crash on tableView Reload

Tags: ios, swift

I have a category `collectionView` on which there are category `labels` on each cell when I click any cell the `label` Value gets passed to second viewController's category variable using `prepareForSegue` and when the value of category variable gets set the `didSet` calls `loadData()` function.

```
func loadData()
{

    let companyData = Database.database().reference().child("CompanyReviews")
    companyData.queryOrdered(byChild: "Category").queryEqual(toValue: category).observe(.value, with: {(snapshot) in
        for child in snapshot.children
        {
            let companyObject = Companies()
            let dataSnapshot = child as! DataSnapshot

            companyObject.companyName = dataSnapshot.childSnapshot(forPath: "CompanyName").value as! String
            companyObject.owner = dataSnapshot.childSnapshot(forPath: "CompanyOwner").value as! String
            companyObject.contactNumber = dataSnapshot.childSnapshot(forPath: "ContactNumber").value as! String
            companyObject.location = dataSnapshot.childSnapshot(forPath: "location").value as! String
            companyObject.gstNumber = dataSnapshot.childSnapshot(forPath: "GSTNumber").value as! String
                self.companyArray.append(companyObject)
            }
            if self.companyArray.count > 0
            {
                self.CompanyTable.reloadData()
                print(self.companyArray.count)
            }
            else
            {
                self.noData.text = "No Data Available"
                self.CompanyTable.backgroundView = self.noData
            }
        })
}
```

If there exists some data under that category the `tableView` loads that data if not then `tableViews backgroundView` shows 'No Data Available'. 
The app runs perfectly. Now there is one category that has no data under it and two categories with data. The problem is that after selecting a category and then coming back and selecting other category the app crashes 
at `self.CompanyTable.reloadData()` with error:

> Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping the optional.

I really don't know why is this happening, I searched on google and even went through some answers on stackOverflow but no clues.I am a beginner in `swift` programming so please help me on this issue.

Answer (score 0):

> when the value of category variable gets set the didSet calls loadData()

get rid off `didSet` it's the reason for the crash , you need to call `loadData()` in `viewDidLoad` , the reason is that all outlets of the VC are nil until the VC loads which not true when control is inside the `prepareForSegue` , you may be lucky if network speed is not fast , but you should not leave your app under possibilities

Also replace `observe` with `observeSingleEvent` as the former is observer that's called every change in server